# Automatic Copyright Year - Using PHP

Tags: php

I'm stuck with this, and till now I didn't catch where I'm making mistake. My code in functions page is:

```
<?PHP
    function getDate()
    {
        $found= 2014;
        $curent= date('Y');
        echo $found . (($curent!= $found) ? '-' . $curent: '');
    }
?>
```

and on index page, I called that function with next line of code `<?php echo getDate(); ?>` Error i get is: `HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: Incidentally, a plain old `2014 - <?php echo date('Y'); ?>` would do. Your function is needlessly complicated; it's never going to be 2014 again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn on error reporting or consult your server's logs (this is a critical part of developing in PHP), you'll see the following:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare `getDate()` ... on line 7

That's because [`getdate`](https://www.php.net/getdate) is already a built-in PHP function.